# Endian-safe conversion from uint16 with value less than 256 to uint8

Tags: c++

I am interacting with an API that returns `uint16_t` values; in this case I know that the value is never going to exceed 255. I need to convert the value to a `uint8_t` for usage with a separate API. I am currently doing this in the following way:

```
uint16_t u16_value = 100;
uint8_t u8_value = u16_value << 8;
```

This solution currently exposes endianness issues if moving from a little-endian (my current system) to a big-endian system.

What is the best way to mitigate against this?

Comment: `<<` doesn't care about endianness. Excluding overflow `a << b` is mathematically equivalent to `a * 2**b`

Comment: But if the system is big-endian then the `<<` will result in `u8_value` being 0.

Comment: `uint8_t u8_value = u16_value;`. Done. Implicit conversion will work as intended. If you want to make it explicit, there is also `static_cast<uint8_t>(u16_value)`. I feel that the code you're showing does not entirely reflect the use case described before it, though.

Comment: `u8_value` will be 0 on a little endian system too.

Comment: you can do implicit cast(static_cast in c++/ just copy into uint8_t.

Comment: "endianness issues if moving from a little-endian (my current system) to a big-endian system" What do you mean by "moving", taking the code that runs on your system and re-compiling it on another system, or taking data from one system and passing it to another through a file/network/etc.?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: If it is through network, network layer takes care of endianess.

Comment: @Srini sure, the network doesn't care. But the program at the other end needs to know what endianness the data is in (hopefully "network order").

Comment: @Srini Network layer takes care of endianness only in situations where it knows it's a number. When you pass a buffer of bytes there's no changes performed by the network layer.

Comment: You were bitten by the [byte order fallacy](https://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html). Byte order is irrelevant (until you are writing your data to an external file to be consumed by a different machine). The correct conversion is `uint8_t u8_value = u16_value;` regardless of endianness (or use `static_cast` to be explicit about the conversion).

Comment: @Adam Mitchell: more context is needed to understand the problem. please provide.

Comment: @Srini no, the network layer has no idea. The programmer must insert relevant calls (to `htonl` etc) at the network interface boundary.

Comment: Elephant in the room: what's the `<< 8` doing in there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic)

> For unsigned and positive a, the value of `a << b` is the value of `a * 2**b`, reduced modulo maximum value of the return type plus 1 (that is, bitwise left shift is performed and the bits that get shifted out of the destination type are discarded).

There's nothing about endianness here. You can just do

```
uint16_t u16_value = 100;
uint8_t u8_value = u16_value;
```

or

```
uint16_t u16_value = 100;
uint8_t u8_value = static_cast<uint8_t>(u16_value);
```

To be explicit.

Comment: I suspect the OP described their problem incorrectly, but this is the one-and-only correct answer to the question literally being asked.